# Is it safe to allow an anchor tag in an html editor?

Tags: javascript, html, security, websecurity

I am allowing HTML inside one of the text areas in my application and am now about to block certain HTML elements and attributes, both in client-side and server side validation.

I was wondering if it would be wise to allow an anchor `<a>` tag. I really need my users to be able to type in anchors. However, I am pondering over what all misuses a bad guy could make of an anchor tag.

Here's what I have come up with.

1. An external script could be executed using it. For .e.g

   <a href = "http://external/website/js/function">Dummy text</a>
2. A rogue could simply execute one of my own JS functions from within the origin domain.

   <a href = "javascript::postMethodByMistakeDeclaredInGlobalScope();">Gotchya!</a>

   <a href = "#" onclick = "myobj.myfunction()">Dummy text</a>

Of course, I could mitigate #2 by ensuring everything is properly scoped, but I am just worrying out of a good habit of trying to think of all evil things that can happen so I may incorporate them into my code / design.

Is there any other way someone could misuse an anchor tag?

Comment: Keep in mind that *any* tag can have an inline listener attached to it, eg `<a href="somewhere" onclick="evilFn = function() { alert('evil') }; evilFn();">link</a>`. It's a problem not just with `<a>`s, but any element

Comment: yes, you can have any tag in your editor, but just make sure to sanitize your input and prevent any xss attack. there are some libraries for this

Comment: Like Pars said, there are tried and trusted libraries for this sort of thing - probably better to use them than to try to re-invent the wheel on your own (which may or may not result in a safe outcome)

Comment: @Pars Thanks. I am looking at some. On the server side, I know pretty much how to handle request validation. On the client, I was thinking of doing it on my own but I am now considering using a lib. Would you like to recommend some?

Comment: @user2864740 That has absolutely nothing to do with what I am asking. Are you suggesting I should write a meta language? What exactly are you saying? The question is very specific. Unless I am missing something, I think your comment is an airbrush.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is safe to allow an a tag inside your application.
To answer your question specifically you've covered the most of it, but someone somewhere is trying to thing of new ones.

To get around it using up to date filtering libraries will mitigate xss attacks [link](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#XSS_Prevention_Rules_Summary)

Once, input is formatted correctly (escaping untrusted data), run it through a HTML parser. This takes out anything that is not on an existing whitelist.

You needn't write your own and there are many that already exist [link](http://htmlpurifier.org/), others are available.

P.S. it is recommended you do filtering on the server side and not the client side.
[link](https://github.com/showdownjs/showdown/wiki/Markdown%27s-XSS-Vulnerability-(and-how-to-mitigate-it)#conclusion)